# python-twisted: How to stop the daemon when user logs out?

Tags: python, linux, signals, twisted, daemon

When a user logs out, the twistd daemon process started by this user gets killed. However, it leaves the .pid file, so I would prefer to shut down the daemon in a more elegant way. Ideally, I would react on some signal and use `reactor.stop()`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: When a user logs out of what?

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone: A linux machine, gnome-session in my case, but ideally that should work even when logged in remotely.

Comment: @rafalcieslak, "logout" is a pretty infrastructure-dependent concept.  Logging out of `gnome-session` is a very different event than shutting down an SSH connection.  What distro are you running gnome-session on?  What display manager?

Comment: You are doing it wrong. A real 'daemon' doesn't get killed when user logs out. Read about how to properly daemonize processes. Catch SIGTERM and shutdown properly.

Comment: @Rajesh: I am convinced I am doing this right, I use `twistd` to daemonise my process; however, in some cases (including user logout) it receives SIGKILL and no SIGTERM.

Comment: @Glyph: How about the case when the daemon is started as a dbus service?

Comment: @rafalcieslak: sounds like a new question, probably one with the `dbus` tag :).  Personally, I don't know.

Comment: Are you sure it's not getting `SIGHUP`? (Attaching with gdb should tell you.) The usual shutdown procedure is to send SIGTERM, wait a bit, and then send SIGKILL; if you're getting SIGKILL without a previous SIGTERM then either you're spending "too long" reacting to SIGTERM or there's a bug (or a "feature, not a bug") in whatever's sending SIGKILL. You also shouldn't be getting either if the process has daemonized properly.